# Separating Hours from Time in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a Text data field  which contains the time. ie.
9:10:00 AM.
I would like to split this field into 2 fields, one with just the Hours
portion ie 9
and the other with just the Minutes portion. ie 10.There are some instances where time-stamp is as follows 18:10:00 AM. I tried Left ,Right and some other functions with No luck.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
SELECT 
 left([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie],instr([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie],1,":")-1) AS [HoursPart], 
 mid([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie],instr([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie],1,":")+1,2) as [MinuterPart] 
FROM [Table]
```

Or that:

```
SELECT 
 hour(cdate([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie])) AS [HoursPart], 
 minute(cdate([StrangeTextFieldWithTimeInsdie])) as [MinuterPart] 
FROM [Table]
```

Comment: @santhosha both variants? have you changed source table and field name